# Mac keyboard Option key emulation

Tags: macos-catalina, photoshop-script

I am working with the Wacom graphic tablet and Wacom pen. The Wacom pen button executes a custom Photoshop CC 2020 script. I like to add new functionality to the script to emulate a Mac keyboard modifier key state.

The idea, a Wacom pen button press activates the Option key. A Wacom pen button release deactivates the Option key.

In Photoshop the Option key state is not scriptable. So far, I try making an apple script that did not work very well and required executing the AppleScript file from the Photoshop Javascript file.
What other programming options exist to emulate the Option key toggle from within a javascript file?

Comment: You can't toggle keys with Photoshop JS. I think you're trying to solve a wrong problem and it'd be easier if you've mentioned what you're actually trying to achieve with this.

Comment: I am testing custom Photoshop jsx script which I run through the Wacom stylus button. When the Photoshop stamp tool is selected and the scripts executes the Option key should be on while the stylus button is on.

Comment: The Wacom stylus software allows the user to assign actions to the stylus button including the modifier keys. In my case, have assigned the action to run a custom script. The goal is to add the Option key toggle to the script.

Comment: I have posted the question in the Adobe scripting forum with a visual to illustrate the question.  The visual illustrates what I am trying to do. Let me know if you think this makes sense and is possible?  https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/option-modifier-key-simulation/m-p/11482226?page=1#M470002

Comment: Once again you're not explaining what you want to do (sample an area under a cursor?) but how you want to do that :). Anyway, I believe what you want is impossible with JSX: you'll need to use AS or an app to create macros (quickeys, keyboard meastro, etc)

Comment: When I press stylus I want the Option key on so that I can sample the point below the stylus tip. So, the Option key should stay on while the stylus button is pressed to allow sampling. When the sylus button is released the option key is off. What is AS stand for?

Comment: AppleScript (in this context)

Comment: Can the JSX send an instruction to run a shell script through the command line? For example, a shell script with an if statement. If the Option key state is Off change to On. Else if Option key state is On change to Off.

Comment: yep, you can use `app.system()` to run system commands and pass arguments and `ScriptUI.environment.keyboardState` to determine is Opt was pressed while the script was running